# Get table options from query

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to query the options (specifically the `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`) set for a specific table?

Right now I'm doing `\d+ <table_name>` in the CLI to get them, but I'd like to do it from a query.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE a_a (
    a int
)
WITH (
    autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 20
);

SELECT
    relname,
    relnamespace,
    reloptions
FROM
    pg_class
WHERE
    relname = 'a_a';
```

you will get:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
| relname | relnamespace |             reloptions              |
+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
| a_a     |        16466 | {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=20} |
+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but seems to be parseable so that'll do, if no one has more insights on this, I'll accept your answer in a couple days!

Comment: what are you hoping for. obviously you can do some manipulation to get key value  in reltoptions.

Comment: Of course! I've actually already solved my problem with the example you gave. I just thought that maybe there was a table/view like pg_settings, but table-specific.